# Bit manipulation of Uint32 bitfields in C#

Tags: c#

I have two enums in C#

```
public class PlayerAttributes 
{

        private UInt32 m_AttributeFlagsMask;
        private UInt32 m_AttributeFlagsBitmap;

        [Flags]
        public enum EAttributesFlagsBmp
        {
           AIn = 0,
           BIn = (1 << 1),  //1
           CIn = (1 << 2),  //2
           DIn = (1 << 3),  //4 
           EIn = (1 << 4), //8
           FIn = (1 << 5),  //16
           GIn = (1 << 6)  //32
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum EAttributeFlagsMask
        {
            None = 0,
            AIn = (1 << 1),     //1
            BIn = (1 << 2),  //2
            CIn = (1 << 3),   //4
            DIn = (1 << 4),  //8
            EIn = (1 << 5),  //16
            FIn = (1 << 6)  //32
        }

        public UInt32 AttributeFlagsMask { get { return m_AttributeFlagsMask; } private set { m_AttributeFlagsMask = value; } }
        public UInt32 AttributeFlagsBmp { get { return m_AttributeFlagsBmp; } private set { m_AttributeFlagsBmp = value; } }

        public bool SetAInAndBIn(bool a_in, bool b_in)
        {
            if(a_in && !b_in)
            {
                   UInt32 flag = ((UInt32)PlayerAttributes.EAttributesFlagsBmp.AIn | ~(UInt32)PlayerAttributes.EAttributesFlagsBmp.BIn);

            }else if(bin && !a_in)
            {
                   UInt32 flag = (~(UInt32)PlayerAttributes.EAttributesFlagsBmp.AIn | (UInt32)PlayerAttributes.EAttributesFlagsBmp.BIn);

            }
            AttributeFlagsBmp  = flag  

            return true;
        }
}
```

The above code doesn't seem to set the value correctly. 
What I want is in

`case 1` `AIn` should be set and `BIn` should be unset. (All other bits should be unchanged)

and 
In `case 2` `BIn` should be set and `AIn` should be unset. (All other bits should be unchanged)

how do I achieve this

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you expect `AIn` or `BIn` to be set to anything? Did you mean `a_in` and `b_in` or `flag`?

Comment: A word of caution: `(1 << 1)` is not `1` as your comment suggests, but `2` (1 shifted left by one bit equals 0b10 = 2)

Comment: @knittl - thanks.figured that already

Comment: Ah, the answer to my question is you edited your question. Very different now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is what you want, but if the following line

```
((UInt32)PlayerAttributes.EAttributesFlagsBmp.AIn | ~(UInt32)PlayerAttributes.EAttributesFlagsBmp.BIn)
```

is expected to set A and unset B, while not changing the others, it will not work (it will actually flip all the others). To set A and unset B without changing anything else, you should use:

```
((UInt32)PlayerAttributes.EAttributesFlagsBmp.AIn & ~(UInt32)PlayerAttributes.EAttributesFlagsBmp.BIn)
```

Just like in regular booleans, when negating one side you need to change Or to And (and vice-versa) in the comparison to keep the same behavior.

EDIT:

The reason why the others flags gets erased when you set is because you are setting only those 2 flags on a property and then overwriting whatever exists on the property, by setting the value on it. In order to just change the values that is already on the property, you must use the appropriate operator on its values and then set it back. Like this:

```
AttributeFlagsBitmap = AttributeFlagsBitmap |
    (UInt32)PlayerAttributes.EAttributesFlagsBmp.AIn &
    ~(UInt32)PlayerAttributes.EAttributesFlagsBmp.BIn;
```

Comment: What if I have another function that sets 'DIn`. It doesn't seem to sustain the state across functions?

Comment: Do you realize that you are never setting the class property (AttributeFlagsMask), just setting the local variable (flag)? Local variables doesn't, indeed, sustain the state across functions. You could take a look at this for further undertanding how to work with flag enums (and bitwise operations in general): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_bitwise_operators.htm

Comment: Oooops sorry for the last comment, you are setting the attribute. I also understood what you mean by not sustain the state, I'll update the answer in a moment